# How to return negative integer as valid result using ioctl?

Tags: c, linux-device-driver, kernel-module, ioctl

I need to pass integer to kernel module, calculate sin there and return result.

First of all, kernel has built-in sin `fixp_t fixp_sin(unsigned int degrees)` function, that returns fixed-point number (that can be negative).

So, my question is: if i pass integer using ioctl to kernel module, calculate sin, how i can return negative result back?

ioctl detects negative return values as errors.

Comment: I you are expecting an `int` return value from sine function, all you will ever get is `-1`, `0` or `+1`.

Comment: @WeatherVane i suppose the trick is to use fixed point numbers.

Comment: The return value of an ioctl always relates to the *success* or *failure* of the ioctl.  If you have *data* to pass to or return from the ioctl, you always do that via the pointer argument.  Although with that said, hiding a sin() function behind an ioctl seems like a strange architectural choice.

Comment: @SteveSummit this task is not for real software, but for education purposes. Task is to implement device driver, that calculates sin. I found `ioctl` most painless tool for commucation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need to pass integer to kernel module, calculate sin there and
>   return result.

Instead of passing integer value to `ioctl()`, structure can be passed. This structure can have inputs and output data fields. There is no need to mess with `ioctl()` return values.

**Sample ioctl() with passing struct to char driver**
https://github.com/jeyaramvrp/kernel-module-programming/tree/master/sample-char-dir

Answer (score 2):

`ioctl()` is never meant to return floating point values. But you can pass a pointer to your userspace memory which can be filled:

```
float f = 1.0;
ioctl(fd, SIOCCALCSIN, &f);
```

f is an inout-parameter here, taking the value for which you calculate the sinus and being overwritten with the result.

Comment: @EugeneSh I would not see a reason why

Comment: @WeatherVane I read the question that the OP already has means to calculate the sinus in kernelspace. It is easy to code it by hand.

Comment: Passing an `int` and expecting `int` back (even if signed) is not very siney.

Comment: Because of traps it is involving. Kernel doesn't like to trap itself. Some manual work with FP registers is involved.

Comment: @EugeneSh but that's exactly what kernel_fpu_begin() and kernel_fpu_end() takes care of.

Comment: I didn't say it's impossible. Not recommended unless no other choice. People better be aware of it before considering such a modules.

Comment: @EugeneSh it is obviously a coding exercise, I think it is irrelevant if it is generally a good or bad idea ;)

Comment: @Ctx if i define `int32` in userspace, pass it using `ioctl(fd, SIOCCALCSIN, &myint)` and change it to fixed-point (also `int32`) sin value in kernel module it will also be changed in userspace?

Comment: @Ctx i supposed to access userspace i must use `get_user` macros & do magic with pointers.

Comment: @avasin Which datatype do you use for fixed-point values? There is no native type for that. I personally would use the cleaner interfaces copy_from/to_user(). You can use FP arithmetic when you surround it by kernel_fpu_begin/end()

Comment: @Ctx kernel sin/cos functions use `typedef s16 fixp_t;`, which refers to `s16`, 16-bit (2 byte) signed value

Comment: @avasin Then I would suggest that you use the same format as input parameter. Otherwise I would use a `union { int input; fixp_t output };` if in- and output parameter shall have differing types.